# Show that there is no nth roots in $U$.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

Let  $U\subseteq\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}$ be an open set and suppose that there is a path $\gamma$ in $U$ such that $\mbox{Ind}_{\gamma}(0)=1$.   Show that there is no nth roots in $U$. $(n\geq 2)$

**Remark:** When we say that there is no nth root in $U$, it means that the  function $f(z)=z$ does not have $n$th root $U$, ie, does not exists $g:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic such that $f(z)=(g(z))^n$ for all $z\in U$.

Comment: Open? Or simply connected? Roots of any holomorphic function defined in U?

Comment: What do you mean by no $n$th root in $U$?

Comment: $n$-th roots of what?

Comment: It is already clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let  $U\subseteq\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}$ be an open set
and $\gamma: [0, 1] \to U$ be a closed path in $U$ such that
$\mbox{Ind}_{\gamma}(0)=1$.

Assume that $g:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic in $U$
and satisfies $g(z)^n = z$ for all $z \in U$, and therefore
$$
 n \frac{g'(z)}{g(z)} = \frac 1z \, .
$$

Then $\Gamma := g \circ \gamma$ is a closed path in $U$ and
$$
 \mbox{Ind}_{\Gamma}(0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\Gamma \frac{dw}{w}
 =  \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_0^1 \frac {g'(\gamma(z)) \, \gamma'(t)}{g(\gamma(t))} \, dt
 = \\ \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_0^1 \frac{\gamma'(t)}{n \, \gamma(t)} \, dt
 = \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma  \frac{dz}{z}
 = \frac{1}{n} \mbox{Ind}_{\gamma}(0) = \frac{1}{n}
$$
which contradicts the fact that the winding number $\mbox{Ind}_{\Gamma}(0)$ is an *integer*.

Comment: Why do you say $n\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}=\frac{1}{z}$?

Comment: @DiegoFonseca: Taking the derivative of  $g(z)^n = z$ gives $n g(z)^{n-1} g'(z) = 1$, then divide by $g(z)^n = z$. –  You can also (locally) take the logarithm: $n \log(g(z)) = \log(z)$ and then differentiate with respect to $z$, it is called the "logarithmic derivative".